# Implementing iTune Credential AlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the iPhone, i see a UIAlertView with textFields and buttons (When requesting for iTune credentials).

I too need to have a UIAlertVIew with buttons, textfields and an image to be displayed on it. I don't want to use any external libraries to do this. So is there a way i could implement it. Can someone give me a code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 5 the best thing to do is use the new built-in functionality to accomplish this (UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput).  You don't get an image, though.

If you need the image, or need to target iOS < 5, you can try adding your own fields, but this is contrary to the UIAlertView docs ("The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."), might get your app rejected, and in any event is going to be fragile, depending greatly on the exact display metrics used from release to release.  Not a good idea.

I would instead create my own view (*not* exactly mimicking UIAlertView, since it will come out looking wrong and landing in the "uncanny valley" of UI elements) and, say, display it modally.